# Weird behaviour working on a skip list using void pointers

Tags: c, skip-lists

```
void insertSkipList(SkipList* list, void* I){
  Node* new_node=createNode(I, randomLevel(list->max_level));
  if (new_node->size > list->max_level)   

  Node* actual_node=list->head;
  unsigned int k;
  for (k = list->max_level;k>=1;k--){                          
    if (actual_node->next[k] == NULL || list->compare(I, actual_node->next[k]->item)<0){
      if (k < new_node->size) {                                
        new_node->next[k] = actual_node->next[k];
        actual_node->next[k]=new_node;
      }
    else{                                                    
        actual_node->next = &actual_node->next[k];
        k=k+1;                                                
    }
  }
  }
}
```

I'm having troubles with the command `list->compare(I, actual_node->next[k]->item`
as it doesn't execute at all. The problem is most likely here *actual_node->next[k]->item* but I can't see why.

These are the definitions of node and list

```
typedef struct _SkipList SkipList;
typedef struct _Node Node;

struct _SkipList {
  Node *head;
  unsigned int max_level;
  int (*compare)(void*, void*);
};

struct _Node {
  Node **next;
  unsigned int size;
  void *item;
};
```

The complete minimal reproducible example contained within the question itself is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_HEIGHT 5

typedef struct _SkipList SkipList;
typedef struct _Node Node;

struct _SkipList {
  Node *head;
  unsigned int max_level;
  int (*compare)(void*, void*);
};

struct _Node {
  Node **next;
  unsigned int size;
  void *item;
};


unsigned int randomLevel(unsigned int height);

static int compare_int(void* x_void,void* y_void){
  int x=(int)x_void;
  int y=(int)y_void;
  return x-y;
}

static Node* createNode(void* item, unsigned int lvl) {
  Node* n = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if(n == NULL) {
    printf("\nError! Node memory not allocated.");
    exit(0);
  }
  n->item = item;
  n->next = NULL;
  n->size = lvl;
  return n;
}

SkipList* createSkipList(unsigned int height, int (*compare)(void*, void*)){
  SkipList* skiplist = (SkipList*) malloc(sizeof(SkipList));
  if(skiplist == NULL) {
    printf("\nError! Skiplist memory not allocated.");
    exit(0);
  }
  skiplist->head=createNode(NULL,height);
  skiplist->max_level=1;
  skiplist->compare=(*compare);
  return skiplist;
}

void insertSkipList(SkipList* list, void* I){
  Node* new_node=createNode(I, randomLevel(list->max_level));
  if (new_node->size > list->max_level)   
    list->max_level = new_node->size;
  Node* actual_node=list->head;
  unsigned int k;
  printf("here it's before the loop\n");
  for (k = list->max_level;k>=1;k--){                          
    if (actual_node->next[k] == NULL || list->compare(I, actual_node->next[k]->item)<0){     //here the code stops completely
      if (k < new_node->size) {                                
        new_node->next[k] = actual_node->next[k];
        actual_node->next[k]=new_node;
      }
    }
    else{                                                    
        actual_node->next = &actual_node->next[k];
        k=k+1;                                                
    }
  }
  printf("here it's after the loop (and actually this wont get printed idk why\n");
}

unsigned int randomLevel(unsigned int height){
  unsigned int lvl = 1;
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  while (rand() < 0.5 && lvl < height)
    lvl = lvl + 1;
  return lvl;
}

int main()          //creates a skiplist that goes from 0 to MAX_LENGTH
{
      skiplist=createSkipList(MAX_HEIGHT,(*compare_int));
      int found[MAX_LENGTH];
      int expected[MAX_LENGTH];
      for(int i=0;i<MAX_LENGTH;i++){
        insertSkipList(skiplist,(void*) i);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: [MRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needed.

Comment: Where does your list's head node come from?  Because the `insertSkipList()` function presented assumes that `list->head` is (already) a valid node.

Comment: Code indentation makes this unreadable. And it wouldn't compile. If you want help, meeting the forum halfway is a good idea.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I added the MRE, hopefully that's what you mean

Comment: Well, sort of, but the code must be contained in the question itself, not linked (a link may vanish tomorrow). Fixed for you. What about: `"skiplist.c:26:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size"`? Or, `"skiplist.c:27:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size"`. Or, `"warning: ‘compare_int’ defined but not used"`? -- those look like they need to be addressed. (those are not your problem, but compiling -- those immediately stand out)

Comment: You have given us the code for the skiplist implementation, but we cannot verify the behavior or enlist the aid of a debugger to help answer your question because we have nothing to run the code against. Do you have a `main()` function somewhere with example data to duplicate the weird behavior you are having? (that would complete the MRE) We need to see what gets passed as `SkipList* list, void* I` how/where those variables originate and are initialized or defined.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin here it is, I think you cut it from the link. I added it back

Comment: Okay!! Now the warnings that didn't make a difference because `compare_int()` was unused in the first code in the link now make a LOT of difference with `createSkipList(MAX_HEIGHT,(*compare_int));` used in `main()`. First, you leak memory. You allocate for `skiplist` on your first line, then overwrite that pointer with your second line losing the address to the first block allocated.  In `compare_int()` you cast a pointer to an `int` with `int x=(int)x_void;`. If pointers are 8-bytes and `int` is 4-bytes -- what happens to the other 4-bytes?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I fixed the int problem by just declaring the int as long but the problem persists. Also I fixed the malloc by removing it, still the problem doesn't go away and the method insertSkipList doesn't manage to finish

Comment: I haven't picked through everything with a fine-toothed comb. But they way I will start is to get rid of all the `void` pointers and replace them with proper types. If you haven't fixed `insertSkipList(skiplist,(void*) i);` That is a holy train-wreck. You are creating a pointer holding an address of `0` through `20`. That's an invalid address at the very bottom of the system-reserved range.  When you pass a pointer with a value of `20` and use a parameter of `void* x_void` to take it, the value at that address is completely unreachable and completely *Uninitialized*. Get rid of `void`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i'm doing this for a uni project that requires to do everything in generic code, so I can't take out the void*

Comment: Do it with the correct types first -- then come back an make it generic -- that's the progression.